# Monitor and change SQL queries with SQL Server 2000

Tags: windows, sql-server-2000, odbc

I have a database upgrade tool that is misbehaving. I would like to catch one of the queries it sends to the database and change it before it is executed.

The tool connects via ODBC.

The tool and the SQL Server are on the same Windows 2003 Server box.

Any ideas?

EDIT: (More info)
When the tool runs it dies on step 12 out of 100. It issues some bad SQL intended to create a view. I need to suppress the error message or correct the SQL before it is executed. I can't just create the view because the first thing it does it drop the view. Even then it would error because the view would already exist.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the bad SQL? Is it just a defect, or is it related to SQL versions, or something else? Can you post details?

Comment: @SqlACID - The tool is creating a view with a select statement. The select is missing some columns so... select PoId,,ArgId,App,,Process from wfrProcess. The sql is dynamically generated so I'm not sure where the issue is. This one comes in after about 300 different selects. I have seen this tool work before so I don't think it is a defect in the tool.

Comment: I found the where the tool is selecting from to generate the bad SQL! So my current issue is solved... for right now anyway. I still thing having the ability to do the man in the middle idea would be useful. Maybe like a custom ODBC driver?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly - use the SQL Profiler to intercept and record the query.

Very useful little tool that...

Comment: I can watch the query come in using the Profiler (I love that tool) but I need to change it before it runs. The tool is creating SQL with syntax errors that need to be fixed. I want to do a man in the middle setup where I can monkey with every thing the tool does. Or set the server to replace the query.

Comment: Is there an option in the Profiler I'm missing?

Comment: @NitorxDM: no, you can't change it in profiler. You can copy it into SSMS and change it and run it

Comment: @gbn - That is what I thought. Too bad running it again wouldn't fix the issue.